# using <include> in xamarin android dynamically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a layout in xamarin with two parts: header and body
depends on a property I have to change the header part.
I created 2 layouts to use as header part : header1 and header2
I  used  tag in my xamarin android layout to add my header layout to main layout.

```
<include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/header1" />
```

but I can not change the layout property to header2 dynamically?

Comment: I just want to change  layout="@layout/header1" in c#

Comment: do you have any other solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LayoutInflater is the best solution :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
 View  inflatedLayout = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.yourlayput, null);                  
 LinearLayout ll =  this.Window.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.container);
ll.AddView(inflatedLayout);
```

the function is very good!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ViewSwitcher/), since you only need to switch between two layouts:

.axml

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/headerSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your two headers go here -->

</ViewSwitcher>
```

Create a private field on your Activity/Fragment and initialize it in your OnCreate method:

```
private Switcher _headerSwitcher;

//Inside your OnCreate
_headerSwitcher = FindViewById<ViewSwitcher>(Resource.Id.headerSwitcher);
```

Then you can use `_headerSwitcher.ShowNext()` or `_headerSwitcher.ShowPrevious()` to change between your headers

Comment: Thanks, It works but I am looking for a better way , I want to something like usercontrol, I do not want to change layouts like a wizard

Comment: You could create your own View and then encapsulate this behavior within it, but it would have to do something similar (changing visibilities or inflating new layouts), so this solution is not that different